# My search box does not filter my data in any of my tab controls. (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, search-box

I am still new at using vb.net and I am having trouble making my search box work. I just followed a tutorial in youtube and this was the code I used.

```
Private Sub txt_fsearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_fsearch.TextChanged
    Try
        Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("FullName Like '%{0}%'", txt_fsearch.Text)
        dg_fecalysis.DataSource = DV
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain what does ***"not working"*** mean? Do you get an exception? Is there no data visible after search or it's not filtering? What is not working?

Comment: sorry, you're right. the program runs but my search box doesnt filter the data.

Comment: I guess ***dbDataSet*** is infact a datatable since DataView does not have a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes dataset. Your program would not even build if it was a dataset. Other than that there is nothing wrong in this code, I'm guessin you get an exception, you just don't see it since you catch it and do nothing. Debug your program and see what is wrong, impossible to help with this little code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try building a query

Watch this Video | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y22Z5LCVZ68

---

Right click on **YOUR table adpater** and select **add query**

**name your query** and then click on **query builder button**

In Filter column  "i.e FullName" just write **FullName LIKE ? '%'**

*Then double click on you search button and insert this code*

```
Try      
   Me.YOUR table adapter name.YOUR query name(Me.YOUR table adapter name.Your database table name, "%" & txt_fsearch.Text & "%")
Catch ex As System.Exception
End Try
```